# Decoration in the Chapter Title

Tags: chapters, decorations, psvectorian

I am trying to use a decoration in the chapter title using the `psvectorian` package. The problem is that it doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?

**MWE**

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[raggedright]{titlesec}

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]%
{%
    \LARGE \centering \bfseries%
}{Chapter\\[1cm] \thechapter}{1cm}{}[\psvectorian[scale=0.5]{82}]

\usepackage{fontspec}

\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage{psvectorian}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Text}

\end{document}
```

Comment: 'Doesn't work' is no useful description, but I think the main reason is that `psvectorian` does not compile with `lualatex` and the optional argument of `\psvectorian` must be protected because it is inside an `[...]` already

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I use XeLaTeX and psvectorian in other parts of my document without a problem. The only part that doesn't produce an output is when I use it in the chapter title.

Comment: Yes, I forgot that `XeLaTeX` and psvectorian do work. The main cause is the optional argument

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cause here is that `\psvectorian` does have an optional argument and is used inside another optional argument -- this does not work for commands defined with `\newcommand` etc.

Use `[{\psvectorian[scale=0.5]{82}}]` in order to protect the inner `]` pair from being recognized as the closing of the outer `[`.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[raggedright]{titlesec}

\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]%
{%
  \LARGE \centering \bfseries%
}{Chapter\\[1cm] \thechapter}{1cm}{}[{\psvectorian[scale=0.5]{82}}]

\usepackage{fontspec}

\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage{psvectorian}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Text}

\end{document}
```

[image]