# LaTeX package to insert fancy horizontal lines

Tags: spacing, horizontal

I received a pdf written in LaTeX in which I noticed the use of the following horizontal spacer:

[image: horizontal spacer]

Do you know which LaTeX package provides that one?

Thanks a lot,
Cheers

Comment: The package `psvectorian` provides such lines

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/407680/decoration-in-the-chapter-title for example

Comment: Perfect, @ChristianHupfer, thanks a lot: I found it in that package manual (http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pstricks/contrib/pst-vectorian/psvectorian.pdf). If you write in the answers area, instead here as comment, I will accept your , thank you!

Comment: It was a duplicate of another question, so no need to add another answer...